# Toast after email intent message

Tags: android-intent, toast, email-client

I have an email intent set in my application, and im trying to toast the user after the email is sent.

Here is the "system flow"

User clicks button -> email chooser displays -> send email in client -> "Sending email" generic toast displays -> Custom toast

I have tried putting the toast syntax after the email intent, and onPause method.

Can anyone assist me? here is my sample code.

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScheduleService extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText serviceTime, serviceNeeded, vehicleYear, vehicleMake, personsFirstName, personsLastName, personsEmail,
            personsPhone, comments, vehicleModel;
    // Spinner serviceTime, serviceNeeded;
    TextView serviceDate;
    String fname, lname, phoneNumber, vehicleYears, vehicleModeltrim, vehicleManu, serviceAppointment,
            serviceAppointmentTime, serviceTypeNeeded, extraComments, emailAdd, emailaddress, message;
    Button sendEmail, PickDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.service);
        initializeVars();
        sendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Use the following commented fields for future Spinner properties
    private void initializeVars() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        personsFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        personsLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        personsEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
        personsPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
        // vehicleYear = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sYear);
        // vehicleMake = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sMake);
        vehicleYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tYear);
        vehicleMake = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tMake);
        vehicleModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Model);
        serviceDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tpickDate);
        // serviceTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sTime);
        // serviceNeeded = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sNeeded);
        serviceTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tTime);
        serviceNeeded = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tNeeded);
        comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eComments);
        sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSentEmail);
        // PickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        conversion();
        String emailaddress[] = { "email@example.com" };
        String message = "Please Review the following" + '\n' + " " + '\n' + "First Name: " + fname + '\n'
                + "Last Name: " + lname + '\n' + "Email :" + emailAdd + '\n' + "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber + '\n'
                + "Vechile Year: " + vehicleYears + '\n' + "Vehicle Make: " + vehicleManu + '\n' + "Vehicle Model: "
                + vehicleModeltrim + '\n' + "Requested Service Date: " + serviceAppointment + '\n'
                + "Requested Service Time: " + serviceAppointmentTime + '\n' + "Service Needed: " + serviceTypeNeeded
                + '\n' + "Comments: " + extraComments;

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email@example.com" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Schedule Service Request");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Please select Email Client"));
        Toast.makeText(ScheduleService.this, R.string.myString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void conversion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fname = personsFirstName.getText().toString();
        lname = personsLastName.getText().toString();
        emailAdd = personsEmail.getText().toString();
        phoneNumber = personsPhone.getText().toString();
        vehicleYears = vehicleYear.getText().toString();// Text field substitute
                                                        // for spinner adapter
        vehicleManu = vehicleMake.getText().toString(); // Text field substitute
                                                        // for spinner adapter
        // vehicleYears = (String) vehicleYear.getAdapter().getItem(RESULT_OK);
        // vehicleManu = (String) vehicleMake.getAdapter().getItem(RESULT_OK);
        vehicleModeltrim = vehicleModel.getText().toString();
        serviceAppointment = serviceDate.getText().toString();
        serviceAppointmentTime = serviceTime.getText().toString();
        serviceTypeNeeded = serviceNeeded.getText().toString();

        // serviceAppointmentTime = (String) serviceTime.getAdapter().getItem(
        // RESULT_OK);
        // /serviceTypeNeeded = (String) serviceNeeded.getAdapter().getItem(
        // RESULT_OK);
        extraComments = comments.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is all the vital code? I have created a test application using your code and I have no problem showing toasts. I toast onCreate, after startActivity, onPause and onDestroy. I'm using Android version 2.3.3 on emulator and 2.3.7 on device. API level 10. Can you tell more about your setup?

Comment: Sure, this is just the email and on pause segments. It does toast(myString) however, it seems to toast right after the user presses submit. Wondering if the toast can be triggered after the generic email intent toast.

Comment: This is a basic UI input form, that collects data view editText. on submit the email intent is triggered, and the user sends the form via their email clients. after the send email button is pressed, android toasts "Sending email"; however the user does not receive an "email sent" toast afterwards. hope this helps clarify

Comment: Ok, in my case, the toasts all show up while the email chooser is showing. And you have two lines of EXTRA_EMAIL. I don't know if that is on purpose, and either way it works fine, just have to initialize the variable :)

Comment: I'll post my code as an answer, then you can try to start that activity to see if it fails too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: I think I have misunderstood your problem; from what I can tell now, you want YOUR toast to appear AFTER the email is sent and the email application's toast has been displayed? If that is the case try this:

First remove the `finish()` from your `onPause()` method.

Then, replace your `startActivity` with `startActivityForResult` which takes an extra argument `requestCode`. The `requestCode` is used to separate the results from different activities.

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Please select Email Client"), 
    MY_REQUEST_CODE); // MY_REQUEST_CODE is some constant int >= 0
```

Finally add the following code to *receive the result from your `startActivityForResult`*. Here you can decide which toast to display, depending on the result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("SS", "onActivityResult: " + requestCode + ", " + resultCode + ", " 
        + (data != null ? data.toString() : "empty intent"));
    if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.myString,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.myOtherString, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    finish(); // to end your activity when toast is shown
}
```

If this is what you actually need, I'm sorry I didn't see your problem clearly at first.

---

Old thoughts:

The following is a small application that only shortcuts your manual action (the button) for sending the email intent. This works fine for me. If this works for you too, then maybe your way of calling the "send intent" method from the pressed button has some quirks.

```
package my.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(AndroidTestActivity.this, "Welcome toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"bfdk@dgfsgfds.dfs"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Schedule Service Request");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message goes here");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Please select Email Client"));
        Toast.makeText(AndroidTestActivity.this, R.string.myString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pause toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Destroy toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The activity launches, but the toast still appears when selecting email client. Very Strange

Comment: Do you mean that it works as expected? If so how to do handle the button click? Maybe there is an issue with the click being handled on the main/ui thread?

Comment: After researching the issue, I have found nothing online that references this. I will continue to manipulate the code. You have set me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help more.. I tested your complete example too, and it works just fine for me. All the way from Android version 1.6 to 4.0.3. Have you tried to run it on your phone? Do you get the desired behavior there?

Comment: Whoever it was, when you downvote, please give an explanation/reason for why you did it. Otherwise I cannot argue for my answer, nor improve it. Thanks

Comment: I think the resultCode is always 0, because ACTION_SEND has no output.

Comment: That's true, the documentation states that output is "nothing", i.e. `0`. But it is entirely up to the developer of the application that handles the intent to set a result code or not. I think it was gmail or dropbox that returned 0 or 1 depending on the final user action.